# Converting Minecraft .lvl to .dat

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is it possible to import/convert a Minecraft Classic server level to a Minecraft server level? I have a really old server, set up in McLawl r55, that I would like to open and explore in the current version of Minecraft.

If so, how can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.

First, download [McEdit](https://github.com/mcedit/mcedit/downloads). Open up your Classic .lvl and save it, in McEdit, as a **schematic**. Then, make a super-flat world and open it (or create a new one with McEdit), and paste the schematic where you need it to be. Save it as a Minecraft world.

(Remember that you may need to patch things up; I did this once and I had to seal things up because lava was coming in, and the floor could reach the void.)

Comment: I couldn't open my .lvl files in McEdit for some reason and McLawl no longer worked so I had to download McForge, open it the the World of Minecraft client. Dump the level file, which created a .dat but not in a way Minecraft could understand. From there, I imported the .dat dump file into McEdit and did as you explained. After all that, I haven't even played the old map haha. I guess I was doing it more as a challenge :P

Comment: I just tested this with a _really_ old level file, and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For batch conversion:
https://www.fcraft.net/wiki/MapConverter

Now if only there were a way to combine all the hundreds of schematics into 1 world...

Comment: There's prob. a MCEdit filter for it.