# How can I convert a .lvl map file to Anvil format?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to import [this Enterprise D build](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lXUkdrcey-w) into my Minecraft server. I found it [downloadable here](http://www.minecraftworldmap.com/worlds/4NNed), but it is a `.lvl` file, which is what the custom McSharp server uses.

How can I convert a `.lvl` map file to an Anvil format map (a folder with multiple `.dat` and region files)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question based on how you worded it: "*I ak this apparently narrow question*". This question is too localized and will be unlikely to help any future visitors.

Comment: @Retrosaur I did some research to try to answer this, and discovered that this is a more general problem than the asker believed. I've rewritten it to focus on how to get a `.lvl` map format into something a vanilla server can use (or which can be imported with MCedit).

Comment: A piece of the puzzle, but not a complete answer. A tool like this [map converter](http://www.fcraft.net/wiki/MapConverter) can convert to more common map formats like the Alpha `.dat` format. Then it's a matter of finding a converter from `.dat` to Anvil.

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/57409/converting-minecraft-lvl-to-dat

Comment: @SevenSidedDie or to an MCEdit schematic.  Which is apparently built in.